# Is Compile-time Polymorphism in C++ Templates Possible?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, c++-templates

Consider the following code snippet:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>


template<typename T>
class TypePrinter{
    public:
    void print_type() {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    }
}; // end class TypePrinter


class Base{
    public:
    TypePrinter<Base> createTypePrinter(){ // TODO replace "Base" with the class of the instance.
        return TypePrinter<Base>();
    }
}; // end Base

class Derived: public Base{
};

int main() {
    // Create a derived instance and try to create a TypePrinter for it
    Derived d;
    auto tp = d.createTypePrinter();
    tp.print_type(); // prints "4Base".
    return 0;
} // end main
```

In the example above, I have

- a class with a typename template parameter (`TypePrinter`) and
- another class that instantiate it, using its type as a parameter (`Base`)

How can the code above be rewritten so that the inherited `derived_instance.createTypePrinter()` method can create a `TypePrinter<Derived>` rather than a `TypePrinter<Base>`?

In other words, what modifications could allow `d.createTypePrinter().print_type()` to print "Derived"?

Comment: several possibility according to what your ultimate goal is.
First I would propose CRTP (a random [link](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/programming/9781788832564/8/ch08lvl1sec59/crtp-and-static-polymorphism) on the subject).
In your specific example, it looks like a factory pattern: no need for fancy design, return smart-pointer to base and ```createTypePrinter``` may be virtual.

Comment: [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp) is a well known pattern  in C++, yes? It's usually different from _Generics_ used in other languages like C#, Delphi, or Java.

Comment: You might be interested in the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/crtp), in which a base class receives its own derived class as a template argument and is therefore able to use that information to do things like instantiate a `TypePrinter<Derived>`. [Demo here](https://godbolt.org/z/sz7P1Y8EE)

Comment: @NathanPierson I tend to believe this question is a duplicate of the CRTP stuff. Just an unexperienced, uninformed user.

Comment: C++ templates are using duck typing so yes. CRTP is not required.

Comment: Yep, you all are right. This can be implemented with the CTRP. I guess that really does make me "just an unexperienced, uninformed user"

Comment: @NullPointerException Well, please note, that wasn't meant to diminish you in any way. I actually believe, that the linked stuff should help you to resolve your doubts/misconceptions. No offense ...

Comment: No offense taken; thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this can be implemented with the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>


template<typename T>
class TypePrinter{
    public:
    void print_type() {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    }
}; // end class TypePrinter

template<typename T> // Base is now a template class. 
                     // Subclasses set T to their type
class Base{
    public:
    TypePrinter<T> createTypePrinter(){
        return TypePrinter<T>();
    }
}; // end Base

class Derived: public Base<Derived>{
};

int main() {
    // Create a derived instance and try to create a TypePrinter for it
    Derived d;
    auto tp = d.createTypePrinter();
    tp.print_type(); // Now this prints "7Derived"
    return 0;
} // end main
```